# Can't change context in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, .net-core

I have a project, let's call it Sample. It's a normal class library targeting .NET Framework 4.5.1. Then, i have another project in the solution, let's call it Sample.CoreFx. It's a .NET core project that basically just consists of a project.json file (and of course the generated Sample.CoreFx.xproj file). The project.json looks like this:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "compile": "..\\Sample\\**\\*.cs",

  "frameworks": {
    "dotnet": {
      "dependencies": {
        ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Maybe i should also note that i didn't use a template for my Sample.CoreFx project, but just created the project.json file and in Visual Studio right-clicked my solution and used `Add -> Existing Project` and chose it.

Now, my question: In Visual Studio 2015 there's a drop-down in the upper left corner allowing to switch the context. In my case it shows two entries: `Sample` and `Sample.CoreFx..NET Platform`. But when i choose the latter one and click into the editor again, the selection changes back to `Sample`. This causes that I have no IntelliSense for the .NET Core context. Does anyone have an idea why this behavior occurs?

Comment: I've noticed that when this occurs, I can close the editor window and re-open the same file and the switch seems to "stick". Does that happen for you as well?

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't got Visual Studio installed at the moment so I can't check. It will probably take a while until I'll be able to do so.

Comment: could be permission¿?. Try executing visual studio as an administrator. Colud you post a photo screen about this?

Comment: Try to Rewrite, because some changes with that

Comment: It's been two years since I was using VS 2015 and .NET Core so I can't recall it exactly. Still I'm very sure I was running it as administrator so I think permission is not the issue. Anyways I'm not aware of updates and bug fixes made in the last two years. Maybe someone facing this problem now (I think someone does since the question  was upvoted) can provide more detailed information?